# Allow hotkey that presses a disabled key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

My keyboard key/letter `f` is ruined and continuously presses the letter. I am using AutoHotKey to successully disable the letter, but I need an alternative hotkey to press the key. I have chosen to use `CTRL+j` as the hotkey to press the letter `f`. I tried this script but it does not seem to press the key:

```
f::return

^j::
Send f
return
```

I also tried this but it also does not work:

```
f::return

^j::
Send {f down}
return
```

How can I get the script to press `f` using the hotkey `CTRL+j`, while disabling the key `f`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$` modifier](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) is going to solve this problem.
That modifier makes it so that your `f::return` hotkey wont affect keys that are sent from AHK.

So here's your finished script:

```
$f::return
^j::SendInput, f
```

Also switched over to [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) due to it being the recommended faster and more reliable send mode.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [ASCII code](https://theasciicode.com.ar) for the letters in both uppercase and lowercase, and it also worked:

```
; disable the key 'f':
f::return

; press CTRL+j to press f:
^j::
Send {Asc 102}
return

; press CTRL+Shift+j to press F:
^+j::
Send {Asc 70}
return
```

Comment: Just using `f` or `F` in the send command should work fine.